# switch view via UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have an Xcode project and would like to switch view from one file, file name is Score (without xib, it's only Score.h and Score.m) to the main file (it's name is View and does have a XIB) by using UIbutton in my file Score.m, but I can't do that ..

Using this code :

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(200, 400, img3.size.width/2, img3.size.height/2);
[btn1 setImage:img3 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btn1 setImage:img4 forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self addSubview:btn1];

if(btn1.selected) {
    View *second =[[View alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
}
```

I get this error :  `Receiver type 'Score' for instance message doesn't declare a method with selector 'presentModalViewController : animated`

Please help .

Comment: What's your score? Could you show us the score.h?

Comment: What is the view controller that contains the button? You can call `presentModalViewController` from that view controller.

Comment: You said that View does have a XIB, so you should use it in the initWithNibName then.  `View *second =[[View alloc] initWithNibName:@"View.xib" bundle:nil];`.

Comment: I use UIImageView  as interface for Score.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are receiving indicates, that Score (the class you are trying to push the new ViewController from) isn't a ViewController.
Only ViewControllers can present other Viewcontrollers. The Code for the presentation should be (placed in a ViewController):

```
if(btn1.selected) {
    UIViewController *second =[[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    [self presentModalViewController:second animated:YES];
    [second release]
}
```

Comment: you are right this is the problem but when I put this method nothing happen when I press the button .. also in the score.h I put this : [btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btn1.selected) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        
        [self addSubview:btn1];

Comment: You are right . I will fix the problem by try to make method between same classes .